# Grafana with Elasticsearch - Does not show Metrics/Logs switcher

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

Using Grafana 7.2 and Elasticsearch 7.5.1.

Everyting is up and running in Openshift. Elasticsearch datasource is correctly configured and a very simple Dashboard created.

According to official Grafana documentation (check [this page](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/features/datasources/elasticsearch/#querying-logs-beta)), there should be a switcher to change between Metrics and Logs modes.

[image]

However in the version I am running, I don't see that switch:

[image]

Any idea where did it go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is old screenshot (Grafana 6.x) in the doc. Just switch `Metric` to `Logs`:

[image]

Comment: Just perfect! I hadn't see the value "Logs" in that list. Thank you!!